# Switch order of monitors via command line / shortcut in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, multiple-monitors

My current desktop setup is

```
[2][3][1]
```

where 3 is the main display and 1 is disabled.

I would like to be able to toggle between that setup and

```
[3][2][1]
```

where 3 is still the main display and 1 is still disabled. Essentially, I just want to switch monitors 2 and 3.

Ideally I would like to assign this to a shortcut, but to do so (I think...) I need to be able to do this via command line.

If possible, I'd also like to do this without third party software. [edit: although, if Windows does not support this natively, I would accept a third party solution.]

Thanks!

Comment: If you know what the command is, you could put it in a batch file and make a shortcut that runs the batch file. This will run the batch file in a console window, which will close once it's done. If you set the shortcut to run minimized, you won't see the console window flash before your eyes as the batch file runs and then finishes. Let me know if this helps, and I can change it to an answer for you to accept.

Comment: Once I have the command, I know how to turn it into a shortcut; the problem is I can't figure out the command. :\ Thanks though. :)

Comment: @techie007: slightly different, since it doesn't address how to switch the ordering of monitors; (s)he just wants to toggle monitors 2 / 3 on and off. But some of the third party software mentioned in there *may* be of some use. Still would like a plain Windows solution if possible though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full answer I'm afraid though, since there is 3rd party software that will do this, I'm guessing it should be possible to do with PowerShell or similar.

Nirsoft have the free [MutliMonitor Tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) that could be made to do what you want by having a couple of profiles & switching between them.

I expect that there are others too.

I have to say, I'm not sure why you would want this. Windows is actually pretty good at knowing when you have moved to different monitors and remembering the configuration for each set. I use 2 external monitors both at home and in the office with my laptop and Windows remembers the differences just fine. I wouldn't want to change the configuration away from the physical layout.